# Rate limiting for Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1

Good day, Does anyone know how I can implement rate limiting of an Azure function with .NET CORE 3.1?
I've been doing some research and found that with Azure API Management it can be used to manage rate limiting in Azure function, but it's expensive and I don't know if I'm on the right track to have it as an alternative.

I would like to know if there is any other alternative. I already tried with the library https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll, but the project where I am working is too old to be able to use this library.
Thank you.

Comment: To clarify? Do you want to bypass azure function limit? Or do you want to build api rate limit inside of your own Azure Functions?

Comment: I’m using APIM but the serverless tier, therefore, rate limiting is not permitted. To overcome this, I built my own rate limiting solution using CosmosDB … mainly due to its extreme low latency. It works but isn’t perfect because I limit successful calls only. It’s never a problem though and if it is, a user may get another few calls but doesn’t break the bank.